# Page not found drupal error page doesn't show navigation links

Tags: drupal

Page not found drupal error page doesn't show navigation links. What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually default Drupal behavior to enhance performance. It's kind of annoying. There are several ways around it. The simplest is probably this module: http://drupal.org/project/blocks404

Answer (score -2):

The solution to your problem is to supply us with more detailed information about your problem. Some source code, screenshots, background info. Why? Because your main problem right now isnt that your navigation links aren't working, it's that your question isnt working.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know, I just couldn't resist interpeting his question as the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? I thought I was quite clear. Here's my site: www.sageny.org. If someone tries to go to a link which doesn't exist let's just say http://www.sageny.org/page.htm They get the error page. But the error page doesn't show my navigation links. This is the forest_floor theme. I only changed the images of the theme.

Comment: That's a pretty subjective statement